# Set Activity background without stretching

Tags: android, image, background, aspect-ratio, stretch

I'm trying to set a background image in my Android application.
I have a JPEG image and I want to fill the screen with the height of the image, maintaining the same aspect ratio.

I tried by creating an XML bitmap file in drawable and setting it as:

```xml
android:background="@drawable/background_image"
```

This is the XML

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<bitmap xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:src="@drawable/wallpaper1_1920x1200"
    android:tileMode="disabled"
    android:gravity="center" >
</bitmap>
```

With the 'center' tag it doesn't stretch the image and it doesn't resize it.

Is there any way to show the full height of the image (and cropping sides) maintaining the original aspect ratio?

Comment: You can place image in drawable/nodpi folder so it won't stretch

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap your bitmap with Scale Drawable (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html#Scale)
And then use that drawable as a background for your layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<scale xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:drawable="@drawable/wallpaper1_1920x1200"
    android:scaleGravity="clip_horizontal"
    android:scaleHeight="100%"
    android:scaleWidth="100%" />
```

Comment: It doesn't work.. it give me an error and background is white

Answer (score 0):

One solution might be to turn it into a 9 patch png file, allowing you to define where it can and can't stretch. See http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html, the section near the end on 9 patch images.